# Using glew in Borland 5.02

Tags: opengl, glew, turbo-c

I have to implement VBOs in a very old OpenGL program made in Broldand 5.02, but im getting the folowing error when i try to include GL/glew.h :

```
Info :Compiling C:\fontesusr\vertexbuffer.cpp
Error:  glew.h(269,25):Too many types in declaration
Error:  glew.h(270,27):Too many types in declaration
Error:  glew.h(13275,185):Multiple declaration for 'PFNGLREPLACEMENTCODEUITEXCOORD2FCOLOR4FNORMAL3FVERTEX3F'
Error:  glew.h(13274,185):Earlier declaration of 'PFNGLREPLACEMENTCODEUITEXCOORD2FCOLOR4FNORMAL3FVERTEX3F'
```

the problem appear in the folowing glew code:

```
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
    typedef signed long long GLint64EXT;
    typedef unsigned long long GLuint64EXT;
#else
```

i think that happens because borland 5.02 is a 32bit compiler...

Someone can give me a suggest on what can i do to solve this problem? or another way to implement VBOs without make use of glew libraries?

Comment: Do you really have to use Borland C++? Can you use a more recent compiler?

Comment: yes... the software that im working in is very old and change the compiler will be a very long job. ( i suggested to change, but... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am 99% sure Borland C++ 5 didn't have a 64-bit bit integer type.  It seems to be interpreting `long long` as "many types" and borking at it.

The version of glew you are using wasn't written to support older versions of Borland C++.

You could attempt to hack the glew header files to remove the references to 64-bit types and functions.

Also this might work but I'm not sure:

```
#undefine __BORLANDC__
#include <glew.h>
```

Comment: that worked... getting some link erros now, i ll try to solve this now.